# Method to find / eliminate repetitive strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, string

I am trying to find a solution, in eliminating repetitive string names, say for ex.,
in a literal field, i am populating names of the contributor of certain article's history version, and so, if "ron" has contributed to the versioning of an article 3 times, the name "ron" gets added to this literal control, and outputs "ron" 3 times.

I am trying to find, if a name is repeating twice, i should be able to populate it only one time.  How can i achieve this ?

Comment: A very easy answer would be to look for some sort of set. Sets are data structures that only allow one instance of an object, e.g. "ron", in the structure. That way when you need to extract data from the set, "ron" will only appear once.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your source string is, and what your output would be.

Comment: Hi p.campbell, i am getting the author's name using ektron's api - it's a CMS system - and populating the author's name in a literal control, iterating through the content's versioning authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your setup, I'd either use a StringCollection and just check if the name exists prior to insertion or just add all the names to a List and call Distinct() (extension method in System.Linq). So either:

```
StringCollection Names=new StringCollection();
if(!Names.Contains(Name))
   Names.Add(Name);
```

As CharithJ suggests, or:

```
List<string> Names=new List<string>();
Names.Add(Name);
...
foreach(string Name in Names.Distinct())
{
...
}
```

Either would work well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use dictionary whose keys will be the author name (or the field which you don't want to be repetitive) and values will be the lists of contributors. For example,

```
Dictionary<string, List<Contributor>> contributors 
           = new Dictionary<string, List<Contributor>>();


Contributor contributor = new Contributor("ron", /*other values*/);
if ( !contributors.ContainsKey(contributor.Name) )
     contributors.Add(contributor.Name,new List<Contributor>());

contributors[contributor.Name].Add(contributor);
```

Comment: i am not sure, i could get this to work since i am pulling up the authors' list using ektron api call...but will try out. Thanks for the suggestions @Nawaz

Answer (score 0):

Use C#s .Contains() function to check if the name has already been added to the string

Answer (score 0):

Create a *model* of what you want to achieve (it's like a view model) that drives the rendering of your "report". Then, the model can control this requirement of "only output each name once". Pseudo-code follows:

```
var ron = new Author("ron");
var ronnie = new Author("ronnie");
var report = new HistoryReport();
report.AddVersion(1, ron);
report.AddVersion(2, ron);
report.AddVersion(3, ronnie);
string renderedReport = report.Render();
// output e.g.: 
//   Versions 1 and 2 by ron; Version 3 by ronnie
```

Then you use that ouput to populate your literal control.

If you use simple string substitution, you'll mix up `ron` with `ronnie`.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringCollection authors= new StringCollection();

if (!authors.Contains("Ron"))
{
    authors.Add("Ron");
}
```

Comment: Lists are not suitable for lookups if more than a few items are inside it. Hashset or Dictionary are the datastructures to go for which are for one or 1 million users equally fast. The opposite is true for lists.

Comment: @ Alois : Thanks for the downvote. Does the question say there are few authors? It sounds like there are over 10 items where StringCollection can be a candidate.

Comment: @CharithJ : ya, i am pulling up the contributor's names using ektron's api call, where, for a content could have 1 author(contributor) or mulitple contributor's who could edit the content, or the same author, who could edit and version it multiple times. Thats the part i am trying to remove, if it had the same author multiple times.

Comment: @ Ron : Probably you can use this way.